# Frame rendering a Web Page - turn off javascript

Tags: c#, wpf

How to turn off javascript in a WPF Frame element.  It pops up with a:

"Script Error.  An error has occurred in the script on this page"

```
frame1.Source = new System.Uri("http://www.stuff.co.nz");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of .NET for this application supports it, have you tried using the WebBrowser control?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx

Update:  I found a blog post that has a fix for this, although it doesn't do exactly what you wanted.  It uses javascript script injection to disable javascript errors.  I have not tested this.

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/08/31/disable-javascript-error-in-wpf-webbrowser-control/

Comment: Good thought thanks.. put that in and getting the same errors:   <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Source="http://www.stuff.co.nz"  Width="600" Height="600" Margin="-2,223,0,-170" />   hmmm

Comment: Great stuff - found another link on his site which took me to:  http://www.brentlamborn.com/post/WPF-Web-Browser-ScriptErrorsSupressed.aspx    this worked!